# which goroutine is executed when use sleep in go?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

i am new in golang recently. i have a question about goroutine when use time.sleep function. here the code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func go1(msg_chan chan string) {
    for {
        msg_chan <- "go1"
    }
}
func go2(msg_chan chan string) {
    for {
        msg_chan <- "go2"
    }
}
func count(msg_chan chan string) {
    for {
        msg := <-msg_chan
        fmt.Println(msg)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}
func main() {
    var c chan string
    c = make(chan string)
    go go1(c)
    go go2(c)
    go count(c)
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

and output is

```
go1
go2
go1
go2
go1
go2
```

i think when count function is execute sleep function, go1 and go2 will execute in random sequence. so the out put maybe like

```
go1
go1
go2
go2
go2
go1
```

when i delete the sleep code in count function. the result as i supposed , it's random.
i am stucked in this issue. 
thanks.

Comment: No matter what you do or try. How goroutines are schedule which _can_ run unsyncronized is arbitrary and literally _any_ sequence is as valid as any other. You never must assume or rely on that.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to notice is that there are three go routines and all of them are independent of each other. The only thing that combines the two go routines with count routine is the channel on which both go routines are sending the values.

`time.Sleep` is not making the go routines synchronous. On using `time.Sleep` you are actually letting the `count` go routine to wait for that long which let other go routine to send the value on the channel which is available for the `count` go routine to be able to receive.

One more thing that you can do to check it is increase the number of CPU's which will give you the random result.

```
func GOMAXPROCS(n int) int
```

> GOMAXPROCS sets the maximum number of CPUs that can be executing
>   simultaneously and returns the previous setting. If n < 1, it does not
>   change the current setting. The number of logical CPUs on the local
>   machine can be queried with NumCPU. This call will go away when the
>   scheduler improves.
>
> The number of CPUs available simultaneously to executing goroutines is
>   controlled by the GOMAXPROCS shell environment variable, whose default
>   value is the number of CPU cores available. Programs with the
>   potential for parallel execution should therefore achieve it by
>   default on a multiple-CPU machine. To change the number of parallel
>   CPUs to use, set the environment variable or use the similarly-named
>   function of the runtime package to configure the run-time support to
>   utilize a different number of threads. Setting it to 1 eliminates the
>   possibility of true parallelism, forcing independent goroutines to
>   take turns executing.

Considering the part where output of the go routine is random, it is always random. But channels most probably work in queue which is FIFO(first in first out) as it depends on which value is available on the channel to b received. So whichever be the value available on the channel to be sent is letting the `count` go routine to wait and print that value.

Take for an example even if I am using time.Sleep the output is random:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func go1(msg_chan chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        msg_chan <- fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", "go1:", i)
    }
}
func go2(msg_chan chan string) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        msg_chan <- fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", "go2:", i)
    }
}
func count(msg_chan chan string) {
    for {
        msg := <-msg_chan
        fmt.Println(msg)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}
func main() {
    var c chan string
    c = make(chan string)
    go go1(c)
    go go2(c)
    go count(c)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 20)
    fmt.Println("finished")
}
```

This sometimes leads to [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) which is why we use synchronization either using channels or wait.groups.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func go1(msg_chan chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        msg_chan <- "go1"
    }
}
func go2(msg_chan chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        msg_chan <- "go2"
    }
}
func count(msg_chan chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        msg := <-msg_chan
        fmt.Println(msg)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}
func main() {
    var c chan string
    c = make(chan string)
    wg.Add(1)
    go go1(c)
    wg.Add(1)
    go go2(c)
    wg.Add(1)
    go count(c)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("finished")
}
```

Now coming to the part where you are using never ending for loop to send the values on a channel. So if you remove the `time.Sleep` your process will hang since the loop will never stop to send the values on the channel.

Comment: "One more thing that you can do to check it is increase the number of CPU's which will give you the random result." - that's not necessary, as the quoted documentation states, it defaults to the number of logical CPUs available.

Comment: @Adrian yes it does but sometimes it happen when you run same code on different machine like macos and linux it output different results due to number CPU's. So if OP is using a single CPU then may the result looks synchronized but if it uses a system with multiple CPU cores then he can check the difference in output by changing the number of CPU's.

Comment: That's true, but changing GOMAXPROCS won't help if you're trying to induce parallelism. It effectively can only be used to *reduce* parallelism, not to increase it.

Comment: @Adrian yes I know but OP was asking why when using time.Sleep the order of go routines look synchronized so by testing the program like that OP will get to know that the output will always be random. Because I did run the program on a Single Core CPU it is showing the synchronized result sometimes. But running same program on multiple cores of CPU the output is random.

Comment: Yes, but the only way to get it running on a single CPU on a system with multiple CPUs is to set GOMAXPROCS. The solution wouldn't be to set GOMAXPROCS, it would be to *not* set it.

Comment: @Adrian yes now you are getting my point a little bit. That's what I am saying that setting the GOMAXPROCS will show him the random result so that he will get to know the result will always be random that is the point we want to prove here. The solution is just checking why the result is synchronous.